# RCIA scrutiny reading

Tags: liturgy, canon-law

When there is an RCIA elect in the mass to receive the Rite of scrutiny.  Can the priest choose the gospel of the liturgical year that is different from the Gospel the Rite indicate.  We only have 1 Sunday mass for the Community

Answer (score 2):

**When there is an RCIA elect in the mass to receive the Rite of scrutiny? Can the priest choose the Gospel of the liturgical year that is different from the Gospel the Rite indicate?**

The short answer is no.

A few years ago, I asked our bishop this very particular question after a priest did this in a certain parish.

He categorically said it was not permitted. If a priest decides to use the *Scrutiny Liturgy* at mass, he must use the Gospel readings that are provided for in the *Lectionary*. He is not free to alter the liturgy at will.

A priest may say the readings of the particular Sunday or those of the Rite of Scrutiny. It must be one or the other and not altered at will. Rome regulates the liturgy very closely.

The rubrics on “Readings”

> > 150. The texts and the readings for Mass are always those given for the first scrutiny in the Missal and the Lectionary for Mass among the ritual Masses, “Christian Initiation: The Scrutinies.”
>
> > 151. After the readings and guided by them, the celebrant explains in the homily the meaning of the first scrutiny in the light of the Lenten liturgy and of the spiritual journey of the elect.
>
> It would seem that liturgists and pastors who prefer cycle B or C readings would be moving contrary to the rubrics here.
>
> [RCIA 150-151: First Scrutiny, Liturgy of the Word](https://catholicsensibility.wordpress.com/2009/09/07/rcia-150-151-first-scrutiny-liturgy-of-the-word/)